# How do I use dynamic content in thymeleaf fragments?

Tags: spring-mvc, thymeleaf

I have a spring project set up with thymeleaf and thymeleaf-layout-dialect.

In this project I have a controller

```
@Controller
public class HomeController {

     @RequestMapping(value="/", method = RequestMethod.GET)
     public String showHome(Model model){
         return "home";
     }

     @RequestMapping(value="/info", method = RequestMethod.GET)
     public String showInfo(Model model){
         return "info";
     }
}
```

I also have a layout

```
...
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" 
      xmlns:th="http://www.thymeleaf.org"
      xmlns:layout="http://www.ultraq.net.nz/thymeleaf/layout">
<body>
    <div layout:fragment="header">
        dummy header
    </div>
    <div layout:fragment="content">
        dummy contents
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

and two views: home.html and info.html which have different unique contents

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" 
      xmlns:th="http://www.thymeleaf.org"
      xmlns:layout="http://www.ultraq.net.nz/thymeleaf/layout"
      layout:decorator="layout">

  <body>

    <div layout:fragment="content">
        unique contents
    </div>

  </body>

</html>
```

and a header

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" 
      xmlns:th="http://www.thymeleaf.org"
      xmlns:layout="http://www.ultraq.net.nz/thymeleaf/layout">

<body>
    <div layout:fragment="header">
        username is ${username}
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

I'd like to print the username in the header without passing it as an attribute on the model in the controller methods. So, Can I run some custom java code before the header is included to find out the username regardless of what controller method is beeing used? What options do I have?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you would use Spring Security in combination with the [Thymeleaf Spring Security](https://github.com/thymeleaf/thymeleaf-extras-springsecurity3) module, you can do the following:

```
<span class="user-info">
    <small>Welcome,</small>
    <span sec:authentication="principal">Username</span>
</span>
```

If you don't want to use Spring Security, you can write a custom dialect/processor which inserts the username for you.

Comment: Thanks, that was exactly what I was looking for. I also found out that you can add attributes to the model using Interceptors, but this solution is more elegant.